# replace a function with constant string argument with macro in C

Tags: c, macros

In a project I work on we have some utility functions which taking 2 arguments,one is address to write and second is value to write.

Lets use a simple example:

```
enum {
ADDR1 = 0x1000,
ADDR2 = 0x1500,
....
};

void Hardware_write_reg(ADDR,val)
{
switch ADDR {
case ADDR1 : abc.x = val; break;
case ADDR2 : abc.f = val; break;
.....
.....
}
```

This function "Hardware_write_reg" are called in many number of times in many files throughout the project with different ADDR and values as arguments.

Now,I need to remove the calls to "Hardware_write_reg" and write directly to struct members.
An example,Function1() below need to be changed

Before change:

```
Function1()
{
Hardware_write_reg(ADDR1,val1);
Hardware_write_reg(ADDR2,val4);
Hardware_write_reg(ADDR7,val6);
.....
}`
```

After change:

```
Function1()
{
abc.x = val1;
abc.f = val4;
abc.s = val6;
.....
}
```

I cannot do it manually,because many numerous calls to Hardware_write_reg() in multiple files.

I tried with C Macro,like this;but could not get expected result

```
#define Hardware_write_reg(ADDR1,A) do{\
abc.x = ((A));\
}while(0)

#define Hardware_write_reg(ADDR2,B) do{\
abc.f = ((B));\
}while(0)
```

Basically,I want to replace (at compile time)

```
1) Hardware_write_reg(ADDR1,val1); function call to abc.x = val1; with a macro
2) Hardware_write_reg(ADDR2,val2); function call to abc.f = val2; with a macro 
3)....
```

Any help from C-Guru's would be appreciated!

Comment: What prevents you from doing `Hardware_write_reg_ADDR1(val1)` instead?

Comment: It is not possible to replace the contents to be determined in part of C by preprocessor. I think that there is a need to be replaced as defined in the `#define` an enum at least.

Comment: Do you need the `ADDRx` enums for other purposes than calling this function?  You could possibly do `#define ADDR1 abc.x` etc. and then `#define Hardware_write_ref(ADDR,val) ADDR=val`.

Comment: are ADDR1, ADDR2 etc same over all files? In that case a simple text substitution over files would do it and you end up with more readable code than wrapping everything in macros. Just my 2c.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a bunch of macros which does

```
#define target_ADDR1 abc.x
#define target_ADDR2 abc.f
#define CONCAT2(a, b) a##b
#define Hardware_write_reg(ADDR,val) CONCAT2(target_,ADDR) = val
```

so that

```
Hardware_write_reg(ADDR1,42);
```

is replaced by

```
target_ADDR1 = 42;
```

and thus

```
abc.x = 42;
```

is what you get.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it, but I am quite sure this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of programatically solving this you can try regular expression replacement which included in most of the text editors today. but here the problem is for each case in switch you have to modify regex for a bit. And you should not have any other *Hardware_write_reg* in your code.

search

> Hardware_write_reg(ADDR1,val([0-9]+));

replace with

> abc.x = val\1;

Also if you have many cases you can generate regex and replacement with a small script.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could imagine that works for this case is you put the assignment operations into a switch statement

```
#define Hardware_write_reg(ADDR,A) do{\
    switch((ADDR)) { \
    case ADDR1: abc.x = ((A));\
    case ADDR2: abc.f = ((A));\
    ...
    } \
} while(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the C Macros cannot guess the values of ADDR during compile time and hence cannot put appropriate structure member for each ADDR.

As you want replace the function call with the actual assignment statement. So it seems like the only way you can do it is to Find/Replace in the code. For this you can write a regular expression and find a replace using that. For instance for ADDR1:

Find the Regular Expression:

`(Hardware_write_reg)[(](ADDR1)[,]([\w]*)[)];`

And Replace it with:

`abc.x = $3;`

The above regular expressions are compatible in eclipse